How to copy files in Ubuntu to Android data folder?
I want to copy a Minecraft Resource Pack file from the Downloads folder on my Ubuntu 24.04 system to the Android Data folder, however when I try to paste the file into the Android Data folder, the system shows a libmtp error: could not send object error message. Even when I click Try Again I still can't paste the file.
OS: Ubuntu 24.04
Android: Samsung Galaxy Tab S9+, Android 14

If you have developer option on your Android you can look into Android Debug Bridge
